# VS migrating from 2005 to 2010, LNK1316: duplicate managed resource name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, managed-c++

i'm migrating C++ .NET solution from vs 2005 to vs 2010
i receive in managed project a linker error:
LINK : fatal error LNK1316: duplicate managed resource name\

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, but replacing $(InputName) to $(FileName) or $(ProjectName) did not help. What helped was moving the resource file to the project root directory and leaving the "Resource Logical Name" blank in Properties->Managed Resources->General.

Answer (score 1):

Is it this? :

[Link...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/ae5dc280-ef35-4024-a71c-dfc58b65cfb8)

EDIT: I'll summarise the answer below to save reading all the comments :

When VS2010 converted the project file from VS2005, it found a macro $(InputName) which is no longer used. It replaces it with %FILENAME. To fix this problem, go to Properties, Managed Resource, Resource Logical Name and change it to %(FileName).

Comment: That link is from 2005, I think its not relevant.  But, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. Have you opened the .csproj file in a text editor and looked to see if there is a .resx specified twice?

Comment: the .resx file appears only once, but .resource appears twice, once in\<Configurations>
  <Configuration  ...     <Tool
    Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
    ResourceFileName="$(IntDir)\$(RootNamespace).$(InputName).resources"
   />     and in another place under <Filter
   Name="Resource Files"  ... <Tool
      Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
      ResourceFileName="$(IntDir)\$(RootNamespace).$(InputName).resources"
     />  is this a problem, which one can i remove?

Comment: Neither. Are you using %(Filename) to specify a path? See this here where someone was having a problem. http://cmdtqna.com/questions/c6feba2e18f211e09dbc/style-macros-not-supported-in-some-ccli-project-property-pages-under-vs2010

Comment: this seems to be similar problem, but they don't have an answer. VS 2005 macro was $(InputName), that automatic conversion changed to %FILENAME, and i tried to change it to $(ProjectName). none of these is working. as i understand  $(InputName) is cancelled, conversion puts there %FILENAME to indicate it needs to be changed. %FILENAME isn't a macro, right?

Comment: For a test, what happens if you replace %Filename with the actual name of the file. Does your error then disappear?

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your help. if i replace %FILENAME with actual file name for each resx file, in Properties, Manged Resource, Resource Logical Name, then it works. But this doesn't seem to be a good solution. do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did Oleg not answer that question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064793/migrating-macro-from-vs2005-to-vs2010

Comment: In the "Resource Logical Name" textbox press the down arrow and select <Edit...>. Press "Macros>>" and put % into the new text box that appears. You will see several %(xxxx) options. The one called %(Filename) should have the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Visual Studio 2010.  In [this case](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534099/link-error-lnk1316-duplicate-managed-resource), it was

> an issue with project system not
>   removing the extra Form2.resx that you
>   change the form2.h from header type to
>   Winform type.

I suggest going through your solution to see if you have any resources that should be removed when file types are changed.  They said they might fix it in an updated version, but since the workaround is so easy (delete the file) they aren't going to worry about it.