# migrating macro from vs2005 to vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am migrating from visual studio 2005 to 2010.
In the properties in 2005 I had a macro named $(InputName) which doesn't exist in 2010. The suggested value is $(ProjectName). But i think its not correct, i need input file name macro.
what is the best macro to replace the previous?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010 use %(FileName) instead of $(InputName)
Notice that first character is '%'